# = txtSelect->GetValue(); C++, Segmentation fault. This is strange

Tags: c++, linux

In a simple C++ test app in Code::Blocks on Linux, I have a wxTextCtrl named txtSelect, it contains: 'SELECT * FROM user;'

When I run the following, Crash!

```
void refreshGrid()
{
wxTextCtrl *txtSelect;
 wxString sqlLine = txtSelect->GetValue();
}
```

The gdb result is below:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/dan/Documents/wxW_Projs/wxSQLi_417/bin/Debug/wxSQLi_417 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000410662 in refreshGrid ()
    at /home/dan/Documents/wxW_Projs/wxSQLi_417/wxSQLi_417Main.cpp:199
199  wxString sqlLine = txtSelect->GetValue();

(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000410662 in refreshGrid ()
    at /home/dan/Documents/wxW_Projs/wxSQLi_417/wxSQLi_417Main.cpp:199
#1  0x0000000000410593 in wxSQLi_417Frame::OnButton2Click (this=0x7143c0, 
    event=...)
    at /home/dan/Documents/wxW_Projs/wxSQLi_417/wxSQLi_417Main.cpp:183
#2  0x00007ffff6d461fe in wxAppConsoleBase::CallEventHandler(wxEvtHandler*, wxEventFunctor&, wxEvent&) const ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff6ecc6e7 in wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventIfMatchedan(wxEventTableEntryBase const&, wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff6eccace in wxEvtHandler::SearchDynamicEventTable(wxEvent&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff6eccb5f in wxEvtHandler::TryHereOnly(wxEvent&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff6eccc13 in wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventLocally(wxEvent&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0
#7  0x00007ffff6eccc75 in wxEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0
#8  0x00007ffff75f3de8 in wxWindowBase::TryAfter(wxEvent&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0
#9  0x00007ffff6ecc9e7 in wxEvtHandler::SafelyProcessEvent(wxEvent&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
```

---

I have another app in the same PC, with a simple password demo that uses the same simple code and works perfectly, and many others.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `txtSelect`? Does it point somewhere valid? Do you follow [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)? And without a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we really can't help you.

Comment: txtSelect value in first sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`txtSelect` is pointing to nowhere. You should create an object which the pointer points to and then use it, something like this:

```
wxTextCtrl *txtSelect = new wxTextCtrl();
wxString sqlLine = txtSelect->GetValue();
```

If the allocation fails `new` throws an exception `std::bad_alloc`

Comment: That solved it Thank you very much.  I can't imagine how my other examples are working without the wxTextCtrl.. reference.

Comment: Using an uninitialized pointer is "Undefined Behaviour". Anything could happen, it could run, it could crash.